# How to write case statement to display only 1 row in flag column for an ID with 2 different values

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery, greatest-n-per-group

I have a query with multiple joins that is being used to extract data from multiple tables.
As part of the select I have multiple case statements.
I a stuck with one of them. I need to add one condition where I get only one row each for Chris and John with flag 'Y', if they have PCT as 100 and the '0' or 'NULL' PCT rows should not be displayed.

| DeptID | Employee | PCT | Utlility_PCT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | Chris | 100 | Y |
| 101 | Chris |  | N |
| 101 | Sam | 0 | N |
| 101 | John | 100 | Y |
| 101 | John |  | N |

Currently my case statement is case when PCT = 100 then 'Y' else 'N' end Utility_PCT

I want my result set to look like:

| DeptID | Employee | PCT | Utlility_PCT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | Chris | 100 | Y |
| 101 | Sam | 0 | N |
| 101 | John | 100 | Y |

Answer (score 0):

What you describe is filtering, and requires a `WHERE` clause. We can use `ROW_NUMBER()` to enumerate the rows according the priority rules that you describe, then use that information to filter out.

You are not showing your current query, so I'll assume it comes from a CTE:

```
with res as (... your query ...)
select *
from (
    select r.*,
        row_number() over(
            partition by deptid, employee
            order by case when pct = 100 and utility_pct = 'Y' then 0 else 1 end, pct, utility_pct
        ) rn
    from res r
) r
where rn = 1
```

The query limits the result to one row per department / employee tuple; when there is a row with `pct = 100 and utility_pct = 'Y'`, it is selected, else we get the row with the smallest `pct` and the smallest `utility_pct` (this can be adapted by modifying the end of the `order by` clause of the window function).

Answer (score 0):

Since there is a tag **'greatest-n-per-group'** you could filter the rows using GREATEST() function:

```sql
Select *
From   tbl t
Where  PCT = GREATEST( (Select PCT From 
                            (Select DEPT_ID, EMPLOYEE, Max(Nvl(PCT, -1)) "PCT" From tbl Group By DEPT_ID, EMPLOYEE) 
                        Where DEPT_ID = t.DEPT_ID And EMPLOYEE = t.EMPLOYEE)  )
```

With your sample data:

```sql
WITH
    tbl AS
        (
            Select 101 "DEPT_ID", 'Chris' "EMPLOYEE",  100 "PCT", 'Y' "UTILITY_PCT" From Dual Union All
            Select 101 "DEPT_ID", 'Chris' "EMPLOYEE", Null "PCT", 'N' "UTILITY_PCT" From Dual Union All
            Select 101 "DEPT_ID", 'Sam'   "EMPLOYEE",    0 "PCT", 'N' "UTILITY_PCT" From Dual Union All
            Select 101 "DEPT_ID", 'John'  "EMPLOYEE",  100 "PCT", 'Y' "UTILITY_PCT" From Dual Union All
            Select 101 "DEPT_ID", 'John'  "EMPLOYEE", Null "PCT", 'N' "UTILITY_PCT" From Dual 
        )
```

... the result is:

| DEPT_ID | EMPLOYEE | PCT | UTILITY_PCT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | Chris | 100 | Y |
| 101 | Sam | 0 | N |
| 101 | John | 100 | Y |

If there could be more rows per group than in the sample you should probably do some additional filterings and/or groupings.
Regards...